# Fragment save the state of a listener

Tags: android, android-fragments

In an Android Fragment, which is a part of a ViewPager, there is a ListView with EditText for filtering.

```
filterEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.filter_friends);
filterEditText. addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

When I navigate to another Fragment **ondestroyview** is called and then when I navigate back to this fragment **onCreateView** is called and the filtering doesn't work anymore, though the instance variables still exist.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_game_facebook, container,
            false);

    return view;

}
```

How this situation should be handled correctly?

Comment: I have a feeling you should save out whatever data is required from the listener for the destruction, then at recreation initialize the listener with the data - rather than somehow hack the listener instance to stay alive.

Comment: I'm not trying to hack it - the reason I'm asking this question is to solve it the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter, which will destroy all non-active fragments to save memory. This is helpful for when you do not know how many fragments you will use until runtime, but is overly aggressive if you know which fragments will be in the pager. Try using a FragmentPagerAdapter instead,  which will not destroy the fragments as soon as you navigate away from them, so you will not need to manually persist the state of each fragment and reload it.

Comment: I actually use FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: In that case, you will want to override the onPause method to save the data, and onResume to retrieve it. SharedPreferences would probably be the easiest way to save the data if all you need is the string from the EditText.

Comment: Actually what I want to know is how to keep the listerner functional.

Comment: Then you might define it as static in the parent activity rather than local to the fragment. This way, you only ever have one instance of the listener which is unaffected by the fragment's lifecycle

Comment: Yes, but the listener is attached to a view, so if the Fragment view is re-created I guess it wouldn't be a good solution.

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand the issue fully. Why do you need to save the state of the listener? What happens to make it necessary to have the same listener as opposed to a new one each time?